# how to setup dnsmasq for DNS for private and public hostnames via different DNS servers

Tags: linux-networking, internal-dns, hostname, dnsmasq

lets say i have this private hostname `dev.private.example.com` that is only accessible in a private network over VPN connection and i have `prod.example.com` that is accessible to the internet. I have DNS servers to resolve the private hostname and then i can use the public DNS servers(google, cloudflare etc) for the public hostnames.

i will like setup dnsmasq(let me know if there is another tool) so that it will query DNS server for the private hostnames and if it is another hostname then it will resolve via the public DNS servers

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: answer is below..thanks

Comment: we try to shy away from duplicate questions and duplicate answers.

Comment: This is a better question and a better answer than the steaming pile that is linked as being the original Q&A. Even the question title on the other linked question is wrong.

Comment: thank you @Justin
some of the admins on this site got attitudes and i just dont worry myself much..i told them this question is not same but the guy couldn't take no for an answer and still went ahead to mark as duplicate...thanks for cosigning on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what worked for me

edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and have this in the file

```
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d/,*.conf
```

and then create a file in the conf directory `/etc/dnsmasq.d/private.example.com.conf`

and add the following in the content of the file

```
#dont use hosts nameservers
no-resolv
#use following default nameservers
server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.8.8
strict-order
#serve all *.private.example.com queries using a specific nameserver
server=/private.example.com/140.82.113.1
server=/private.example.com/140.82.113.2
```

where the following are the nameservers `140.82.113.1` and `140.82.113.2` resolving the private hostname

then restart dnsmasq

`service restart dnsmasq`

now any private hostnames *.private.example.com will use those nameservers to resolve!!!

and boom!!!